# Play Framework 2.0 template condition - when

Tags: templates, scala, playframework-2.0

I can't find any documentation of what "when" means in scala template. I've seen it on multiple places like scala samples - forms application. What is the meaning of when, what it's suppose to do when it's true and respectively when it's false? Are there any restriction for this construct? Is there a place where I can see the description of this and others scala template constructs?

Sample code snippet:

```
<li class="@("active".when(nav == "signup"))">
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can see the definition of when [2.0.4](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/2.0.4/framework/src/templates/src/main/scala/ScalaTemplates.scala#L805)/[2.1.0](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/2.1.0/framework/src/templates/src/main/scala/play/api/templates/ScalaTemplate.scala#L120).

It is a member of RichString which takes a boolean predicate by name.  String is implicitly converted to RichString.

This means you can only use when on Strings, and you must pass it an argument of Boolean type.

It will return the String when the predicate is true, and empty String when false.